# Consulta base de datos con count(*)

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla llamada examen y otra llamada preguntas.

Esta tablas están relacionadas con el idexamen.

Mi consulta es mostrar el nombre examen y las preguntas que contiene este:

```
SELECT examen.idexamen,examen.detalles,count(*)
from examen,modulo
where examen.modulo = modulo.idmodulo
and modulo.profesor ="00000100p"
group by examen.idexamen
HAVING count(*) IN
(SELECT count(*) from preguntas
 group by preguntas.examen)
```

Al hacer esta consulta no me muestra nada, no veo el error. ¿Alguna solución?

Comment: ¿Qué código usas para obtener esos datos? Probablemente no estás blindando la consulta, perdiendo el mensaje de error que te está dando. ¿Podrías reproducir el problema en una página que nos permita ayudarte como, por ejemplo, https://www.db-fiddle.com/? Gracias :)

Comment: No veo los campos que relacionan las preguntas con el módulo o el examen.

Comment: Útiliza el LEFT JOIN o RIGHT JOIN como te he puesto aquí abajo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes realizar el trabajo usando `INNER JOIN` y cambiando la agrupación del campo `preguntas.examen` a `examen.idexamen`:

```
SELECT
  examen.idexamen,
  examen.detalles,
  count(*) total
FROM modulo
  INNER JOIN examen
    ON examen.modulo = modulo.idmodulo
  INNER JOIN preguntas
    ON preguntas.examen = examen.idexamen
WHERE
  modulo.profesor = "00000100p"
GROUP BY
  examen.idexamen
```

Te recomiendo que por temas de rendimiento uses como consulta externa la que usas como restricción en el `WHERE` para evitar buscar relacionas innecesarias que serán posteriormente filtradas.

Además, para detectar el caso en el que no haya ningún registro para mostrar, se puede agregar el típico bucle `while (.. = ..->fetch())` un `fetchAll` con un `if` para detectar la ausencia de datos y un `foreach` para sustituir al `while`:

```
$f = $consulta->fetchAll();
if (count($f) == 0) {
  $cadena .= "<tr><td colspan='4'>No hay registros</td></tr>\n";
} else {
  foreach ($f as $f1) { 
    $cadena .= "<tr><td>" . htmlspecialchars($f1['idexamen']) . "</td><td>" . htmlspecialchars($f1['detalles']) .
      "</td><td>" . htmlspecialchars($f1["total"]) . "</td><td><a href='mostrarexamen.php?id=" .
      urlencode($f1["idexamen"]) . "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open icon1'></span></a> <a href='editarpreguntas.php?id=" .
      urlencode($f1["idexamen"]) . "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil icon1'></span></a></td></tr>";
  }
}
```

Comment: vale muchas gracias por el consejo.Voy a probar.

Comment: No me muestra nada.

Comment: Como te puse en el comentario a la pregunta, ¿qué código PHP usas para obtener la información? Podría ayudarte a blindar la consulta, obtener cualquier mensaje de error y, si necesitas más ayuda, quizá sea necesario que hagas un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) usando, por ejemplo, https://www.db-fiddle.com/ .

Comment: He detectado un pequeño error que quizá sea el culpable de lo que te pasa. ¿Has probado a cambiar la agrupación a examen.idexamen?

Comment: vale me sale bien si hay preguntas pero cuando no las hay sale vacio y yo querría que me saliera el examen, y si es cero que salga cero.Estoy haciendo lo db-fiddle.com

Comment: ¿Entonces lo que quieres es que te aparezca '0' cuando no haya preguntas cuando no existe el profesor o el profesor existe pero no tienes exámenes?

Comment: Aquí al iniciar sesión me muestrar los exámenes de los ciclos donde el profesor sea el dni al iniciar sesión. Y en la tabla esa me muestra el nombre y el número de preguntas que tiene el exámen y en caso de no tener preguntas me salga cero.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58825/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-bsg).

Comment: Cuando puedas no olvides marcar la pregunta como correcta y, si lo deseas, un voto positivo por el tiempo en el chat :) Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con esta SELECT usando LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT e.idexamen, e.detalles, count(*) 'Total preguntas'
FROM examen e LEFT JOIN modulo m ON e.modulo = m.idmodulo 
LEFT JOIN preguntas p ON e.idexamen = p.idexamen 
WHERE m.profesor ="00000100p" GROUP BY e.idexamen
```